# how to get value of current row in Crystal Reports formula?

Tags: loops, crystal-reports

I have a formula in Crystal Reports that needs to sum only a certain number of values, but can't seem to figure out how to get the current value of a field for a current row. I only get the very last row value.
I am using a loop like so:

```
Local Numbervar loop1:= Maximum ({ReportCommChecksSumm5Year;1.finalMonth});
local Numbervar i;
local Numbervar total:=0 ;
for  i:=1 to loop1 do (
   total:= total + tonumber({ReportCommChecksSumm5Year;1.Year1}) //this always returns the very last row value
);
total;
```

There are basically 12 rows of data from the database, but only the 12th row is accessible, so looping through the rows is impossible.
Is there any way to process a current row? You can do this in SSRS, but I can't find any way of doing this in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in SSRS, in CR you can only access values from current report section (and additionally values of last and next row).

So it seems you could just sum up the required values, i.e. add an aggregate field "sum" into report footer or group footer.

Aggregating a field depending on others could by achieved by creating a new formula field that returns the value of the original field only when the conditions are met, and then aggregating on this new formula field.

For an example of the latter see this answer: [Crystal Reports SUM formula help. Don't SUM values with specific IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043182/crystal-reports-sum-formula-help-dont-sum-values-with-specific-ids/69043404#69043404)

Comment: I used a second query and did a cross join from the SQL side. I can't sum via groups as I have to have all the data before I can determine how to group things (to determine how many items to be summed). A catch-22, but I did the kludge workaround as usual (from SQL). (I don't understand how CR can perform calculations which requires memory of all rows of data, yet doesn't allow access via these rows programmatically!)

Comment: Afaik it can only perform calculations according to its own grouping (as mentioned above), or "in the order the records are printed", which might solve you problem. I'd recommend to try with "running totals", or manipulating shared variables. It might help if you add an actual example to your question.

Comment: I have to test each row AFTER all rows are "consumed" by CR's engine. That's the problem: all reference to original data is gone. You can't group based on anything that requires information that can only be gleaned AFTER ALL rows are consumed - like having a dependency of data that comes later, then adjusting output/formatting/formulas for the earlier data. (you can only do forward-only processing)

Comment: That's right, grouping by a value that's calculated this way (RT or shared vars) is not possible in CR.