# How to summarize the total of a field excluding suppressed values in SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I have a report to display sales report. But there is a duplicate data due to an input error (human error).

here is my report design
[image: design report]

the result

[image: the duplicate entry]

How do I summarize the total by group without including one of the two double data?

I've tried to suppress the column by including the condition suppress by idcust and specific invoices number.

```
{SALES_REPORT_MAIN.CNTITEM}=previous({SALES_REPORT_MAIN.CNTITEM}) and 
{SALES_REPORT_MAIN.IDSHIPNBR}=previous({SALES_REPORT_MAIN.IDSHIPNBR})and 
{SALES_REPORT_MAIN.IDCUST}="0357-00" and
{SALES_REPORT_MAIN.IDINVC} in "INV220004425" to "INV220004426"
```

and then I added formulas using numbervar whileprintingrecords on `{@SumAmount}` field

```
whileprintingrecords;

numbervar qty;
qty := qty + Sum ({@Amount}, {SALES_REPORT_MAIN.IDCUST});
```

and the result is as follows
[image: result of suprress]

but if you sum up the total, the number will definitely not be **49xxxxx but 25xxxxxx** . the total summary still adds up the data that has been suppressed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crystal Reports SUM formula help. Don't SUM values with specific IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043182/crystal-reports-sum-formula-help-dont-sum-values-with-specific-ids)

Comment: What is the scope of the deduping needed?  I'm seeing a potential issue because INV220004426 clearly has a duplicate record, whereas INV220004477 appears to only duplicate the first field, but has more distinct data in the remaining fields to detail a Management Fee and a Cleaning Service.  If you dedupe only on the invoice number, you are going to lose either the management fee or the cleaning service on some invoices.

Answer (score 0):

Add a formula that uses the suppress condition like this:

IF {your suppress condition} THEN 0 ELSE {the value to summarize}

Then, sum that formula.

Comment: Thank you in advance. I have tried entering the formula you suggested into ```{@SumAmount}``` and the result is still the same. can you suggest a condition if (somefield) is duplicate?